# How do I change the login screen background in macOS Mojave?

Tags: login-screen, mojave, wallpaper

I just updated to macOS Mojave, and immediately noticed a couple of things:

- My custom login screen wallpaper is gone.
- When you click on a user's name in the login screen, it switches to their personal background (their usual wallpaper for the first space on the primary monitor).

I assumed it had just overwritten my cached image file. But when I went to replace it, nothing happened. It turns out that `com.apple.desktop.admin.png` is gone entirely!

[image: no-cached-image]

Right after taking that screenshot, I decided to poke into Desktop Pictures and found my personal login screen background, which looks promising. It contains one other folder, which  <del>probably</del>  *(edit: confirmed)* contains the login screen background of my administrator account.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've fixed it! You'll have to edit the dune HEIC picture though. If you're willing, follow these steps:

​1) Go To: /Library/Desktop Pictures/

2) Find the file called "Mojave.heic"

3) Save a copy as a backup somewhere else

4) Select the picture you want to have instead

5) Edit image values (DPI, size, etc.) to fit

6) Rename this edited picture as Mojave.heic

Comment: Good thinking, except this "removes" the Mojave background in the Desktop Background preference pane.

Comment: That definitely might be acceptable! I take it SIP won't trigger, since it's in `/Library`? And it has to be HEIF, right? Most of my images are JPEGs, so I'll have to figure out a way to convert them for this. Maybe `sip`.

Comment: You can just rename a whole jpg file as Mojave.heic and it works just fine.

Comment: @Leonard Interesting. You've tested that, and it works? I'm quite surprised, but that's fantastic!

Comment: @BlackPearl tried this, and it didn't work. I don't know all the specifics of the attempt, though.

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked perfectly, thank you! The resulting image is very dim, but I suppose that's unavoidable. If you don't mind, I'l make another answer with more detail.

Comment: Hm, apparently it still doesn't work on the FileVault login screen. Well, we're halfway there...

Comment: Renaming a jpg file to Mojave.heic does absolutely nothing for me. I also edited the dimensions to match the original Mojave.heic file. Moving on...

Comment: This does NOT work if filevalut is turned on.

Comment: @VinnyTroia It does work perfectly with FileVault enabled, you just have to make the EFI system pick up the changes. (See [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337881/251848) below.)

Comment: @vytalman You did stick it in `/Library/Desktop Pictures` after renaming it, right? (This answer wasn't perfectly clear on that.) And this won't change your personal login background (i.e. the background after you click your user to log in), for that you just change your first wallpaper.

Comment: Ok, so this does the trick for the Multi-User lockscreen background. But what if I want to have 3 different images: one for my desktop background, one for my own lockscreen background (triggered by Ctrl+Cmd+Q), and one for the main user switch background?

Comment: @Myoch Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to make the lock screen use anything other than your current wallpaper. But it uses the background for the _current_ space rather than the first space, which is what the "personal login screen" (e.g. fast user switching) does. You should ask another question about that! If it's the "personal login background" you want to change, I actually have a solution for you.

Comment: It's weird, i have a 'lockscreen.png' image on /Library/Desktop Pictures/4C84182A-C2E2-4F9C-A731-E8D85E487FE1/ instead of this .heic file

Comment: I had to perform a 7 step: Open the System Preferences app and go to the Users & Groups preference. Click the Login options button, and change any one of the options on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on [Leonard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337596/251848):

You can do this by replacing the `Mojave.heic` default desktop background. This **does not require disabling SIP**, as it's in `/Library`.

- Back up `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave.heic` by copying it to `Mojave.heic.orig` or similar.
- Get your new image and scale/crop it to *exactly* fit the display. If you don't know your screen resolution, you can go to  > About This Mac.
- Replace `Mojave.heic` with your new file. Don't worry if it's JPG or similar, it'll still work even after you rename it to `Mojave.heic`.*
- If you have **FileVault** enabled, change a login option in System Preferences. For example, whether to show a list of users or name and password fields. Just change it back if you don't actually want it changed.

  This is because when you boot with FileVault, at the login screen *your system hasn't really booted up all the way*! It's actually running a tiny system on your EFI partition, since your main partition is encrypted. Changing a login option will make System Preferences change the EFI system's settings, including picking up the wallpaper change. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/364587/768408).
- Reboot and enjoy!

<sub>* I've only tested this with JPEG images, but it may work for other types.</sub>

---

### Completely Unnecessary Timesaver

I've made a small Swift program that does all this for you (it detects the OS version and works both on Mojave and earlier versions). You'll need Xcode to compile it.

It shouldn't break your system, but I can't guarantee anything -- **make sure you have backups first!**

<sub>This is now also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/SilverWolf32/loginwindowbgconverter). It may or may not be updated here in the future.</sub>

```
//
// loginwindowbgconverter
// by SilverWolf
// 2018-09-27
//

import Foundation
import AppKit

func printUsage() {
    print("""
    usage: \(CommandLine.arguments[0]) \u{1B}[4mimage-file\u{1B}[0m
    It needs to be run as root, as it saves to /Library/Desktop Pictures.
    """)
}

guard CommandLine.arguments.indices.contains(1) else {
    printUsage()
    exit(1)
}
let inputFile = CommandLine.arguments[1]

guard let inputImage = NSImage(contentsOfFile: inputFile) else {
    print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): can't load image from \(inputFile)")
    exit(2)
}

let iw = inputImage.size.width
let ih = inputImage.size.height
let iaspect = Double(iw) / Double(ih)

// use System Profiler to get screen size

var sw = 0, sh = 0

enum ScreenSizeError: Error {
    case foundNil
}
do {
    let task = Process()
    if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
        task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh")
    } else {
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    }
    task.arguments = ["-f", "-c", "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution/{print $2, $4}' | head -n 1"]
    
    let stdoutPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = stdoutPipe
    
    if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
        try task.run()
    } else {
        task.launch()
    }
    task.waitUntilExit()
    
    let data = stdoutPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    guard let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw ScreenSizeError.foundNil
    }
    let sizes = (text as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "").components(separatedBy: " ")
    sw = Int(sizes[0]) ?? 0
    sh = Int(sizes[1]) ?? 0
    guard sw != 0 && sh != 0 else {
        throw ScreenSizeError.foundNil
    }
} catch {
    print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): can't get screen resolution")
    exit(3)
}

print("Screen size: \(sw)x\(sh)")

var nw = 0, nh = 0
var x = 0, y = 0 // offsets

let saspect = Double(sw) / Double(sh)
if saspect > iaspect { // screen is wider
    nw = sw
    nh = Int(Double(sw) / iaspect) // keep input image aspect ratio
    y = -1 * (nh - sh) / 2 // half the difference
} else { // screen is narrower
    nh = sh
    nw = Int(Double(sh) * iaspect)
    x = -1 * (nw - sw) / 2
}

// draw into new image
guard let newImage = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                                pixelsWide: Int(sw),
                                pixelsHigh: Int(sh),
                                bitsPerSample: 8,
                                samplesPerPixel: 4,
                                hasAlpha: true,
                                isPlanar: false,
                                colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB,
                                bytesPerRow: sw * 4,
                                bitsPerPixel: 32) else {
    print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): can't create bitmap image to draw into!")
    exit(2)
}

NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: newImage)
NSGraphicsContext.current = graphicsContext
graphicsContext?.imageInterpolation = .high
let r = NSMakeRect(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y), CGFloat(nw), CGFloat(nh))
print("drawing rect: \(r)")
inputImage.draw(in: r)

graphicsContext?.flushGraphics()
NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

print("image size: \(newImage.size)")

// write to file
if #available(macOS 10.14, *) { // macOS Mojave has a completely different system
    let targetFile = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave.heic"
    let origFile =  "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave.heic.orig"
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: origFile) { // no backup of original Mojave.heic
        print("Backing up original Mojave.heic (this should only happen once)")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: targetFile, toPath: origFile)
        } catch {
            print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): \u{1B}[1mbackup failed, aborting!\u{1B}[0m \(error.localizedDescription)")
            exit(1)
        }
    }
    
    print("Saving to \(targetFile)")
    // actual writing
    let imageData = newImage.representation(using: .jpeg, properties: [:])!
    do {
        try imageData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: targetFile))
    } catch {
        print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): can't write image data: \(error)")
        print("(are you root?)")
        exit(1)
    }
} else {
    let targetFile = "/Library/Caches/com.apple.desktop.admin.png"
    print("Saving to \(targetFile)")
    let pngData = newImage.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])!
    do {
        try pngData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: targetFile))
    } catch {
        print("\(CommandLine.arguments[0]): can't write image data: \(error)")
        print("(are you root?)")
        exit(1)
    }
}

//
// This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
//
// Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
// distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
// binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
// means.
//
// In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors
// of this software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the
// software to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit
// of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and
// successors. We intend this dedication to be an overt act of
// relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this
// software under copyright law.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
// IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
// OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
// ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
// OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//
// For more information, please refer to <https://unlicense.org/>.
//
```

Comment: To get the screen dimensions you can use NSScreen frame property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388387-frame

Comment: I tried that. It returns the "fake" screen size used for layout, not the real, physical screen size.

Comment: And multiplying it by the backing scale factor doesn't work either: it returns a flat 2 for me, even though I'm using higher density scaling. So it can be larger or smaller than the physical size, depending on your scaling settings. (:

Comment: Ah OK, I get what you mean:)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I even tried the program but with no success. I'm still getting the default dune instead of my picture. I have FileVault enabled but I changed login option as you described. Any ideas?

Comment: @ArtemM Do you see your change on the non-FV login screen, with "Login Window" after you've already logged in? I've had some trouble getting it to show up at boot myself. I ended up changing the display to Name and Password, locking and restarting System Preferences, then changing it back.

Answer (score 1):

I receive a weird image when I just replace the file with a JPG, renaming it too HEIC. However, when I take the image I want as the background and export it in the HEIC format in Preview, it all works great. I was working with a 5333×3333 image to start with:

1. Open image you want as your background in Preview
2. In Preview, select File > Export...
3. Set the Format to HEIC and Quality to best (I got a completely blank image when I tried a quality less than "Best")
4. Rename the exported file as Mojave (the extension should already be .heic)
5. Copy exported image to `/Library/Desktop\ Pictures`

When you logout, you should see your new background. Try restarting, if don't see the image show up right away.

If you run into issues with exporting the file as .heic, try adjusting the size of the image using Preview: Tools > Adjust Size. As a start, set it to the size of your screen as seen in System Information > Graphics/Displays.

Comment: Thank you, good to know! Also, I wrote a small program to do all this automatically if you don't want to resize it with Preview, and it can now export to HEIF. You can find it over [on GitHub](https://github.com/SilverWolf32/loginwindowbgconverter).

Answer (score -1):

**This problem is driving me crazy for months!**

**Here is my solution**

(no FileVault activated)

My wife and I are working together in the home office since Corona. We both have MacBooks. I noticed that her Mac immediately shows her background as wallpaper for the login - but not on my Mac. So what was the difference?

After looking at the solution in the various forums, I noticed that the login screen of macOS would change immediately the default wallpaper when selecting one user out of multiple users. so if there is only one user on the Mac -> its background is displayed immediately.

So there must be something on her Mac that is missing on my Mac! :-|

Apparently it was a folder that macOS probably can't (or doesn't want to) create itself when it is deleted from the cache (Library/Cache/Desktop Pictures)

TLDR:
[image: user settings]

- Copy the UUID of your User-ID.
- Go to "/Library/Caches/Desktop Pictures"
- Create a new folder with your UUID.
  [image: library folder]
- now you should adjust the permissions for the folder so that macOS has write permissions there
  [image]
- If you change your background now, macOS should be able to create a "lockscreen.png" file here.

[image]