# Wallpaper not updating on startup/login screen

Tags: macos, wallpaper

I have updated my wallpaper recently and now when I restart my computer or logout, my old wallpaper still shows (blurred, obviously) on the login screen. When I login, my new wallpaper is there. Is there a way to fix this?

Unfortunately this possible duplicate does not address my issue:
[How do I change the login screen background in macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337445/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-background-in-macos-mojave)
This is not after updating to Mojave OS. I have not updated to it. So I do not have a "Mojave.heic"

Comment: there is already answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/337445/46541

Comment: You can replace `/Library/Caches/com.apple.desktop.admin.png` with your own file, making sure it's sized to exactly match your screen resolution. My program in [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337881/251848) to the other question can actually do all that for you -- it checks the OS version and handles both pre- and post-Mojave.