# Independently change Lock Screen and Login Screen background image in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, login-screen

First of all, this question requires some terminology.

- I'll refer to the **Lock Screen** as the screen you see when you lock the screen.
- I'll refer to the **Login Screen** as the screen you see after a restart before you login.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337445/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-background-in-macos-mojave) gives a great method for changing the **Login Screen** background image. I've found other sources that give the same answer. However I've not found any way to change the **Lock Screen** background image to be something different from the Desktop's background image. Is there a way to do that?

Furthermore, when I choose **Logout [user]**, I see what I have called the Lock Screen, not the Login Screen as I would expect. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: When I hit  > Log Out <user>... I see a popup dialog, not a full-screen modal interface. Did they recently change that, or am I clicking something else?

Comment: Oops, never mind. Ignore my previous comment. (:

Answer (score 2):

Mojave will use the desktop image from your first desktop on the lock screen.

The easiest way to change the lock screen to something else is to add a desktop, and drag it to be the first desktop and change it to what you want the lock screen to be.

Comment: Right. I want to be able to change the lock screen without changing the desktop image.